# Binding command parameter of data grid context menu to selected row's column value

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, contextmenu

I have a datagrid being binded to an ObservableCollection. The data grid has a context menu. When context menu item is clicked, the binded command gets triggered, but I would like to pass command parameter that is binded to the Id of the data grid row that is selected. The command gets triggered but the parameter is null.

Below is the code that I have tried.

```
 <DataGrid Name="users" ItemsSource="{Binding UsersModel}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="User Id" Width="auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" Header="User Name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsRegistered, Converter={StaticResource BoolToYesNoConverter}}" Width="auto" Header="Registered" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RegisteredOn}" Width="*" Header="Registration Date"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Modify" Command="{Binding Modify}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Delete}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

I am expecting the Id of the selected row be passed as the command parameter.

Comment: try setting command parameter to "yay" and you will see it is beeing carried on

Comment: the porblem is related to the fact that the context menue has its on datacontext as far as i am aware

Comment: "Modify" is my ICommand property. My window datacontext is set to UsersViewModel, items source is binded to UsersModel which is an ObservableCollection<UsersModel> type.

Comment: And in which class is the "Modify" property defined?

Comment: @mm8 "*The command gets triggered*", so the command properties are obviously defined at the main view model level, where the UsersModel property resides. `{Binding Id}` will obviously not wok there.

Comment: @Clemens: Right.

Comment: @AbhilashHazarika: So how is your `ICommand` and property implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a SelectedRow property on your viewmodel to store the selected row in the grid, then bind the context menu item command to a command on the viewmodel that references the SelectedRow property.
I had to use the PlacementTarget on the context menu relative source.

// in viewmodel

```
public DelegateCommand ModifyCommand { get; }

ModifyCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => { var Id = SelectedRow.Id; //... });

private UsersModel _selectedRow;
public UsersModel SelectedRow
{
    get => _selectedRow;
    set
    {
        _selectedRow = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRow));
    }
}
```

// in view

```
DataGrid Name="users" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}" >

// and on context menu
<MenuItem Header="Modify" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.ModifyCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
```

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the SelectedItem Binding is redundant. It already binds two-way by default.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `SelectedId` property to your view model (where the `UsersModel` and the command properties are defined) and bind the DataGrid's `SelectedValue` property to that property.

Then use `SelectedId` for the CommandParameter Binding. Of course make sure that `SelectedId` fires the PropertyChanged event.

```
<DataGrid ... SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}">
    ...
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Modify"
                      Command="{Binding Modify}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedId}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                      Command="{Binding Delete}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedId}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score -1):

I asuume that your `ViewModel` class implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and I assume that you implement a method for trigger property changes, here I called this method `RaisePropertyChanged`. After all of that,
define a private field `selectedUsers` and a property with name of `SelectedUsers` in your viewModel Class:

```
private UsersModel selectedUsers;

public UsersModel SelectedUsers
    {
        get => _selectedFields;

        set
        {
            _selectedFields = value;
            Modify.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            Delete.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

After that you add it, you must add `SelectionChanged` event to your `Grid`, and then in code-behind set-up value for your seletedUser as below:

```
private void usersGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        usersViewModel.SelectedUsers = usersGrid.SelectedItem as UsersModel;
    }
```

And bind `selectedItem` of `DataGrid` to `selectedUser`:

```
<DataGrid Name="users" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" 
IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}" >
```

When you do these work, `selectedUser` is accessable in your viewModel.